# RegEx Ranges with .00 number format

Tags: regex

I want to build ranges from numeric values. 
Values can be any value: 1.00, 2.00, 3.00 ... 674.00, ... 891.00 ...

Ranges: 1-10, 11-25, 26-50, 51-100, 101-200, 201-350, 351-600 , >601

I am struggling with the format of the numbers. the ".00" is killing me. I already did some research and tried:

```
([1-9]\.00|1[0]\.00)
```

to fit to the range "1-10", but this puts every number to this range.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?
Thank you for your support.

Comment: Does your regex system support "lookahead" and "lookbehind"? You can place a negative lookbehind to ensure that the match is not preceded by a digit.

Comment: Or use word boundaries `\b`

Comment: Feels like a problem that is much better suited to be solved with a couple of lines of code than a dozen regexes.

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the answer to my own question :-D

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnDvv.png)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the image thing. now text: 
range 26-50 
regex ^(2[6-9]|[34][0-9]|50)$

range 26.00-50.00 
regex ^(2[6-9].00|[34][0-9].00|50.00)$

this now works. I use the regex within Adobe Analytics zu group numbers into ranges.